# Strange behaviour in Apache mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this hierarchy,

```
root/
 |--sections/
 |--test/
 |--.htaccess
```

In the .htaccess file, I have this rule to replace all the 't' with 'a',

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase "/"
RewriteRule "^(.*)t(.*)$" "$1a$2" [R,L]
```

If I access **localhost/sections**, the result is **localhost/secaions/** (with mod_dir enabled), but when I access **localhost/test**, the rule is not applied and the result is **localhost/test/**.

I tried **tessst, tett, tttt**, etc. It only happens to **test**. Is test a remained keyword of Apache or something?

Comment: There is nothing special about the word "test" on Apache. Do you have any files whose basename is "test"? eg. `test.php`, `test.html`, etc? Also, make sure you've cleared your browser cache. The mod_dir redirect to append the trailing slash is a 301, so will be cached by the browser (test with the object inspector open and caching disabled - if you aren't already)

Comment: @MrWhite No... and my Apache configuration is almost default. It's probably parsed as a folder as mod_dir adds on the trailing slash. Strange...

Comment: If `/sections` works then so should `/test`. Incidentally, if `/sections` becomes `/secaions/` (with a trailing slash) then the mod_dir `/sections` to `/sections/` redirect must have been cached. Otherwise, with an empty cache, you should see `/secaions` (no trailing slash).

Comment: @MrWhite Thanks for your reply. Actually, I'm not that familiar with the Apache configurations. Do you mean that the 301 redirect will be cached by the browser as well?

Comment: @MrWhite (following the last reply) I tried clearing the cache before doing each test, and the result is different. I found that /.htaccess won't be applied to all the existent folders under /, but it will affect nonexistent names under /, while if it's an existent folder, the trailing slash will always be added. Should this be the normal behaviour? Thanks, mate.

Comment: By default, 301 redirects are "persistently" cached by the browser. Do you have more directories/files than the example in your question? The directive won't be applied if you have an additional `.htaccess` file in the subdirectory that also uses mod_rewrite. eg. if `/test/.htaccess` exists and contains `RewriteEngine` then the above directive to replace `t` with `a` will not run. Also, if `/secaions` exists as a directory then you will indeed get an additional 301 redirect to `/secaions` - but these scenarios don't exist in your question?